# export result of the query with INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql

I don't find the exported file into /tmp folder. Where MYSQL export that file ?

```
mysql> SELECT oid,t FROM mytable INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/bbb.txt' CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
ERROR 1086 (HY000): File '/tmp/bbb.txt' already exists
mysql> \q
Bye
usr@locahost:/tmp$ ls -l /tmp
total 210308
-rw------- 1 jetty  jetty         0 Feb 27  2014 31020.jsvc_up
-rw------- 1 root   root       2210 Dec 13  2013 apticron.hFScRvN3T6
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root       4096 May 25  2014 graphs
srwxr-xr-x 1 root   root          0 Aug  6  2014 haproxy.socket
drwx------ 2 jetty  jetty      4096 Feb 27  2014 hsperfdata_jetty
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root       4096 Jun 16 04:45 hsperfdata_root
drwx------ 2 usr    users      4096 Jul 15 03:36 mc-usr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root         64 Jul  5 15:18 puppet_failures
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr    users        64 Jul 15 03:29 puppet_failures00
usr@locahost:/tmp$
```

Comment: `/tmp/bbb.txt` will exist on your server. Do you run MySQL server on localhost?

Comment: find it I connect to database from another server and files are generated on db